# Employee Scheduling Problem MIP

Tags: linear-programming, mathematical-modeling, simplex, mixed-integer-programming

I am trying to create a mathematical model for employee scheduling.

I have already got an idea on how I should model it but I do not know whether it is the best way to do it so.

Take for example a day.

A working day consists of 10 hours, from 10:00 till 20:00.

Suppose there is an employee working for 4 hours.

Now such a schedule can start from 10:00 and is dependent on the working hours of that employee.

The way that the available schedules could be written in the **A** Matrix ($A*x \leq b$) would be one column per schedule filled with 1's and 0's.

e.g.

For the 4 hours schedule, I would have 7 different available shifts.

- 10:00 to 14:00
- 11:00 to 15:00
- ...
- 16:00 to 20:00

For that, I would need 7 columns. The first would be filled with

- 1,1,1,1,0,0,...,0

the second with

- 0,1,1,1,1,0...,0

and so goes on.

This way in the **A** matrix I will have many columns with 0 as matrix Elements. Is there a more efficient way to model such a schedule?

My goal is to solve it as a MIP problem.

Comment: This is a good approach. And if you cannot generate all the feasible columns a priori you can do column generation (which does it dynamically). But can be tricky to implement.

Comment: @Kuifje Thank you for your comment. Could you please provide an example or a link of the dynamical creation of the columns? I still find it performance-wise quite "expensive". If I I would implement it for multiple employees and days that would create a massive Matrix.

Comment: Check this for example : https://gist.github.com/Bart6114/8414730

Comment: See [link](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2017/01/employee-scheduling-ii-column-generation.html) for an example of CG applied to employee scheduling (the links at the bottom show alternative approaches).

Comment: @Erwin Kalvelagen Lovely! Thank you for the link. This is what I was looking for. I still have to read multiple times the content on your page to comprehend it. To that, the first reference (Loren Shure) on your page is what I have in my mind. I find such methods so fascinating but I do not know, whether there is already commercial software that is applied in practice e.g. Starbucks employee Scheduling.